# Websocket not working in jmeter

Tags: websocket, jmeter

In Jmeter while using websocket sampler I am getting error like

- Cannot connect to the remote server
- Waiting for messages for 20000 MILLISECONDS
- WebSocket session wasn't started (...that's odd)
- WebSocket client closed by the client

Also request and response are blank in View results tree. Kindly help me to sort out this issue

Comment: - Which websocket plugin are you using?

Comment: - What happens when you do a http request to the same server address?

Comment: For HTTP request it works fine

Comment: - Which websocket plugin are you using?

Comment: Any error info in the jmeter.log file?